# How to receive notifications from a Amazon SQS queue

Tags: ruby, amazon-sqs, peddler

What is the most efficient way to receive messages from a Amazon SQS queue?

I've been using the Peddler Gem to create, register and subscribe to an Amazon SQS queue that captures Amazon Marketplace order changes. All good there, the SQS queue is receiving the messages fine. The next step I'm a bit fuzzy on and need some help before I go down a rabbit hole.

It seems like the SQS queue should just be like a webhook that I can subscribe to, too receive notices. But I'm not seeing that option anywhere.

But then it looks like I can use the Shoryuken Gem or maybe Amazon's own AWS SDK for Ruby to create workers to poll the queue in order to get notified of new messages.

Is the Shoryuken gem the most efficient way to pull messages from SQS? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

IMO [Shoryuken](https://github.com/phstc/shoryuken) is currently the most efficient way for polling SQS messages in Ruby.

You can go ahead and use only the `aws-sdk`, that would work - with certain limitations. If you go on that path, you will ended implementing a lot of stuff around the `aws-sdk`, which Shoryuken already does. With the sdk you can receive messages in a loop, call a Ruby class to consume them etc. Shoryuken is a process for polling messages, which uses multithread for performance wise. Besides that, a single process can receive messages from multiple queues.

> It seems like the SQS queue should just be like a webhook that I can subscribe to, too receive notices. But I'm not seeing that option anywhere.

That is not SQS, the service that's like that is AWS SNS. If Amazon Marketplace can also integrate with SNS, you can implement a pub/sub calling webhooks.

PS: Shoryuken author here :)